# How can I group by and count similar elements in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, frequency

I have a pandas dataframe with many different elements, and I want to group similar ones and add another column representing the frequency of them. For example:

```
+-------+------+
| Atr1  | Atr2 |
+-------+------+
| 1     |  A   |
+-------+------+
| 2     |  B   |
+-------+------+
| 1     |  A   |
+-------+------+
| 3     |  C   |
+-------+------+
```

I want to get:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| Atr1  | Atr2  | COUNT |
+-------+-------+-------+
| 1     |  A    |  2    |
+-------+-------+-------+
| 2     |  B    |  1    |
+-------+-------+-------+
| 3     |  C    |  1    |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Use `df['Atr1'].value_counts().reset_index()`

Comment: I edited the question. Your code works if only I have 1 attribute, but what if I have more than one?

Comment: Use `df.groupby(['Atr1', 'Atr2']).size().reset_index()`